# Improving SQL Query Join

Tags: sql

I have a SQL query that is taking hours to run. My join is on the descriptions of products. Would it be more efficient to create a unique numerical id and join on this instead since the product description is a few sentences long?

Example:

```
SELECT A*, B.something
FROM tableA A JOIN TABLE B
ON A.product_details = B.product_details
```

Comment: Yes, It would be much more efficient to create a relationship using a unique id!

Comment: Try to avoid `varchar` type in `ON` clause specially when you have a large text such as you have `product_details` which may have min of 10 chars or max 500 chars.

Answer (score 0):

For this query:

```
SELECT A.*, B.something
FROM tableA A JOIN
     TABLE B
     ON A.product_details = B.product_details
```

The best index is on `B(product_details, something)` -- however `product_details` is most important as the first key.

I generally recommend a numeric index.  They are a bit more efficient.  And they reduce the number of things to worry about, such as spaces at the ends of keys and collation conflicts.

Comment: Thank you, I'm also getting duplication as well from the join. If I use multiple indexes, will this help as well?

Comment: @MariaNazari . . . If you have another question (such as about duplicates) and you don't find the answer by researching, then ask *another* question, providing sample data, desired results, and explanation of what you mean by duplicates, and an appropriate database tag.